# Получить Context в классе-синглтоне

Tags: android, activity

Имеется класс `MyObject` в котором используется паттерн `Singleton`.

```
public class MyObject  {

    private static MyObject _instance = null;
    private String mMessage;


    private MyObject() {
       DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(*Context*); // Здесь аргументом передается Context
       SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       // Получаем нужные поля из БД
    }

    public static MyObject getInstance(){
        if(_instance==null){
            _instance = new MyObject();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

В конструкторе `DBHelper` нужно передать `Context` для подключения к БД и последующем получении нужных данных.
Есть вариант хранить `Context` в классе-синглтоне наследующимся от `Application`, где получаем `Context` используя метод `getApplicationContext()`.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделайте так

```
private Context context;
private MyObject() {
   DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context); // Здесь аргументом передается Context
   SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   // Получаем нужные поля из БД
}

public static MyObject getInstance(Context appContext){
    if(_instance==null){
        context = appContext;
        _instance = new MyObject();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

из любого активити будете бередавать `this.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Ваш вариант приведет к утечке памяти первой использованной активити, лучше использовать контекст приложения: `this.context = activity.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @xkor спасибо, исправил

Comment: обращение к `this` в статическом методе не будет работать. Нужно для первого вызова передавать `context` в конструктор явно. Поскольку контекст у приложения вроде как один, то потом его можно игнорировать.